# Difference between "kid", "boy", "child", "children"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

I have a question.

What is the difference between entre **kid**, **boy**, **child**, **children**

When is it used?

Comment: Although the answers are correct, "kid" is gender-less, I have heard a number of times where some kids use the word "Kid" to mean specifically a boy rather than a girl. I heard it a few times watching gaming videos where someone asks if the player is a kid or a girl, and in the movie "The Witches" (with Chris Rock and Anne Hathaway) they keep correcting themselves when talking about Daisy, like they will say "She used to be a kid, I mean a girl" (in fact it was this movie that made me google to see if people are now changing it to mean only boys)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A **kid** is any child, either a boy or girl or a baby  goat. It's slang but in common usage.

A **boy** is a male child probably ten years or under, but not always. "The boys are going to the bar." It's a slang for men getting together to have fun. It's casual not literal. (You can substitute girl/s for boy/s and female for male.)

A **child** is a person, male or female, usually under ten, but it's flexible too. My 16 year old is still **my** child but she is not **a** child.

**Children** is simply the plural (more than one) of child.

Comment: Good addition, pointing out that "boys" can be used colloquially to refer to a group of men.  However, I think "kid" only applies to baby goats.  Other baby animals have their own terms, "puppy, kitten, calf, foal, lamb, etc."

Comment: thanks, I'll edit. I wasn't sure but have just checked.

Comment: @Andrew Kid only applies to baby goats. Is that a joke??

Comment: @Lambie  among animals, I meant.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, but that was not the collocation here.

Comment: @Lambie  I understood Andrew but good point for other ELL readers.

Comment: @Lambie yes, I see that now.  Shame I can't go back and edit comments.

Answer (score 3):

> Child

Someone usually under the age of 13.

> Kid

Informal, somewhat equivalent to child. Can also be used to address someone much younger than you if you want to call attention to their age. Can also be used to refer to young goats.

> Children

plural of child.

> boy

A male child.

Comment: Ha, I think the age might be cultural. We call after-tens: pre-teen(ager)s or teenagers.

Comment: Hence "usually", pre-teen is in common use for 10, 11, 12, but it is not unusual for someone to say the phrase "11 year old child". Someone who is 2 years old might also be called a "toddler", but "child" would still not be inappropriate as a label.